# Select records that have specific count in specific criteria

Tags: c#, linq

Please consider this table:

```
 id         Name            Year          Val1            Val2
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 1          Japan           2010           20              a
 2          Korea           2010           10              a
 3          Japan           2010           10              b
 4          Germany         2011           22              a
 5          Austria         2012           18              a
 6          Austria         2012           17              m
 7          Germany         2013           11              j
 8          Germany         2013           12              j
```

I want to select records that have just 1 record in a year. This is my desire result:

```
 id         Name            Year          Val1          Val2
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 2          Korea           2010           10              a
 4          Germany         2011           22              a
```

How can I do this with `LINQ`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a Grouping with a 'Having' clause. The code below should help or point you in the right direction.

```
        var data = new List<Data>();
        //Method syntax:
        var row = data.GroupBy(k => new { k.Year, k.Name}, v => v)
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
            .SelectMany(o => o)
            .ToList();

        //Query syntax:
        var row2 = (from d in data
                group d by new {d.Year, Name = d.Name}
                into g
                where g.Count() == 1
                select g)
            .SelectMany(o => o)
            .ToList();
```

Added grouping by Name & Year and Query Syntax. Just a note: Both Query & Method Syntax is linq. Just different ways of writing it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Can you show me `LINQ` version. best regards

Comment: This does not give the stated result. The grouping should be by name and year

Comment: I think you should `GroupBy` with `Name` and `Year`.Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Make group of records with same [Name, Year] combination, and throw away all groups that have more than one element:

```
var countries1Record = originalRecords.GroupBy(
    record => new
    {
        Country = record.Name,
        Year = record.Year,
    })
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any())
    .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

I use `Skip(1).Any()` instead of `Count() == 1`, because it is more efficient: why count all 1000 records, if you can stop counting after the first record?

The final Select selects the one-and-only record in the group

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is stored in `rows`:

```
var results = rows.Where(r1 => !rows.Any(r2 => r1.Name == r2.Name && r1.Year == r2.Year && r1.Id != r2.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want check all columns values

Comment: It's not checking all the columns, just the name and year, which is equivalent to the grouping used in other suggested answers